# Pact Testing PactProviderRule not detected

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, microservices, pact

I am starting with Pact test, and I followed the example from [Pact-JVM-Example](https://github.com/mattiasmgn/Pact-JVM-Example), then I created my own test

The Producer returns, the data from a user (a very simple JSON)
{
"id": 1,
"firstName": "name",
"lastName": "last"
}

The consumer test is:

```
  public class HelloControllerTest {
  @Rule
  public PactProviderRuleMk2 provider = new PactProviderRuleMk2("DemoService", "localhost", 8112, this);

  @Pact(consumer = "DemoClient")
  public RequestResponsePact createFragment(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    DslPart userResult = new PactDslJsonBody()
        .integerType("id",1)
        .stringType("fistName","name")
        .stringType("lastName","last")
        .asBody();

    return builder
        .given("There is a user with Id 1")
        .uponReceiving("A request for user 1")
        .path("/user/1")
        .method("GET")
        .willRespondWith()
        .status(200)
        .headers(headers)
        .body(userResult).toPact();
  }

  @Test
  @PactVerification()
  public void doTest() {
    HelloController helloController = new HelloController(provider.getPort());
  }
}
```

And the Consumer class looks like:

```
public class HelloController {

  int port = 8200;

   HelloController(){
    // Will use default port.
    System.out.println("Default port "+ port);
  }

  HelloController(int port){
    this.port = port;
    System.out.println("Custom port "+ port);
  }

  public boolean getUser(){

    try {
    String url=String.format("http://localhost:%d/user/%d", port, 1);
    System.out.println("using url: " + url);
    HttpResponse r = Request.Get(url).execute().returnResponse();
    String json = EntityUtils.toString(r.getEntity());
    System.out.println("json = " + json);
    return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Unable to get user");
      return false;
    }

  }

}
```

I have noticed that when I run the @Test:

```
 @Test
  @PactVerification()
  public void doTest() {
    HelloController helloController = new HelloController(provider.getPort());
  }
```

I am getting a NullPointerException.

The Test is not getting the mock data from the provider, declared in the @Rule

```
@Rule
  public PactProviderRuleMk2 provider = new PactProviderRuleMk2("DemoService", "localhost", 8112, this);
```

I don`t know what is missing, why is not detecting the Mock provider?

Any suggestions,
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to indicate your Pact fragment on the test method.

```
@PactVerification(fragment = "createFragment")
```